# Access CSS animation play state using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css, css-animations

On the end of an animation attached to #profile I would like to start the animation attached to #design how would I change the external css attached to #design from animation play-state: paused; to animation play state: running; using the event listener (see below). Im stuck on the next part (after ("design"). Any help appreciated.

```
document.getElementById("profile").addEventListener("webkitAnimationEnd", function(){ 
var animation = document.getElementById("design")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Extend your code to use the style object property `animationPlayState` in JavaScript. You need not use `webkitAnimationEnd` event anymore, since `animationend` event is supported cross-browser now.

```js
var animation = document.getElementById("design");
var profile = document.getElementById("profile");
profile.addEventListener("animationend", function() {
  animation.style.animationPlayState = "running";
});
```

```css
#profile,
#design {
  animation: moveRight;
  animation-duration: 2s;
}
#design {
  animation-play-state: paused;
}
@keyframes moveRight {
  from {
    margin-left: 0;
  }
  to {
    margin-left: 100px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="profile">Profile</div>
<div id="design">Design</div>
```